# I am trying to use apidoc in ruby-on-rails using yarn package manager in nodejs? Having operating system Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I try to install these messages show: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtjNH.png)

Comment: Which Version from Ubuntu? It has nothing to do with ruby-on-rails, please remove the tag. It would be easier to read if you just copied your console output here.

Comment: Have you tried: '$ npm install -g apidoc' ?

Comment: Thanks for reply I solve the issue using command (npm install apidoc –save) which add apidoc dependencies in package.json